# Can I have an editable entry in my requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

I have an environment which I previously installed into an editable package:

```sh
virtualenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -e ...
pip freeze | grep <pkg_name>
```

> -e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/SPACE/REPO.git@HASH#egg=NAME&subdirectory=PATH

I copeid the `pip freeze` result to a `req.txt` file and installed it into a new environment, and it works.

My question is - how can I make it pull the code to build and install, not from a remote server, but from my local project (like done when running `pip install -e`)

*It would obviously only work on my machine, assuming that project still is there, but this is what I want...*

Answer (score 2):

According to pip documentation ([1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#structure), [2](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirement-specifiers/#requirement-specifiers)), yes, you can have an entry like this in your requirements.txt:

```
-e git+ssh://git@example.com/repo.git
```

Also as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841) has pointed out, one could just specify local URL:

```
-e file:///home/someone/repo
-e file://C:\Users\someone\repo
```

Comment: no. it will download from the remote serer. I want from local

Comment: Just edit `req.txt` to use an appropriate local path (or maybe `file:` URL).

Comment: @chepner does this file url support providing extras, f.ex can we have: -e bar[some_extra] @ file:///foo